# Angular, ng-href make the page to refresh

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-route in angularjs to switch  beteen views , I made it to work, sample code below:

Html:
  Mappings
   New Products
angularjs

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "/MbfProduct/Main"
    })
    .when("/Mappings", {
        templateUrl: "/Mappings"
    })
 .when("/Products", {
     templateUrl: "/Products"
 })
```

})

So everything is OK just I had to add the "#" in the ng-href  attribute so the page doesn't get refreshed.

So my question how can  I have the result, I mean no page refresh, without having the '#' in the href ?

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: I Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function in your controller that changes the view. You have to use `$location` provider to switch between views. There is a method named `path` that does the switching.

Something like this.

```
app.controller("TestCtrl", function($scope, $location){

 $scope.changeView = function(){
    $location.path("/Mappings");
 }
})
```

and call `changeView` function on `ng-click` of anchor tag and just remove the `ng-href` tag altogether. If that doesn't work you can use `ng-href="javascript:void(0)"` as well to give a void link to anchor tag.